Bolt mesh limits became super small in Blender 4.2.1
EDIT: I destroyed everything from Blender on my system and reinstalled it and it's still the same, even in default meters without any scaling... :o
I set my Blender to mm, since I do 3D printing stuff, based on this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZI49VIcISaw
Everything worked fine, except recently the bolt factory became unusable - all sizes are now limited to 0.25mm, just look at this "supposedly" M8:

Any ideas how to fix that?

What do you mean "all sizes are now limited to 0.25mm" ? I don't see any 0.25mm in your screenshot. Also, if it's a bug on the add-on side, we won't be able to resolve it (contact the dev(s) instead).

Check the tiny sizes, I mean 0.0053mm :). Normally blender would round it to like 0.01 (or even 0.1). In any case I cannot go above 0.25, while normally it was like 100mm.

When working in Unit > Length >Millimetres don't change the Unit Scale to 0.001, leave it at 1. Instead, when exporting  as .stl, change the scale there to be 1000. Watch this video for a very good explanation for why scaling is necessary. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hUfPvHPdgR4  (at 10.25 is the scale in .stl export).

Just as @3fingeredfrog says, do not change the Unit Scale in Blender, change the STL export scale. In earlier Blender versions Bolt Factory was creating screws with a wrong scale - the presets produced screws where every measurement was in meters which should have been milimeters. Now it is not broken, but fixed really to use the actual sizes according to Blender units. Of course if you scale down the units with a Unit Scale factor of 0.001, everything becomes tiny. By the way, it wasn't 100 mm max before, but 250 mm (like it still is, scaled down by 0.001 this gives 0.25 mm).

Well, I'm using the 3D printing extension, which exports much easier, but doesn't have the scale... Also until now it was always working...

Ok so I thought I'd temporarily switch to meters to make the bolt and interesting thing happens - the bolt presets not only switch to meters automatically, but it generally doesn't matter - if I create a new project without millimeters and scales, the bolts are still tiny!

Not exactly a fix but a workaround I found.
I tried messing with the units and scaling but nothing worked for me (and it seems you've found the same). What DID work was going to the location of the Bolt Factory extension (in Linux this is .config/blender/4.2/extensions/blender_org/boltfactory/, presumably somewhere in AppData for Windows), and edit the createMesh.py file. Near the top of that file, look for the GLOBAL_SCALE constant, which is set to 0.001 by default; change this to 1. Restart Blender if you have it running, and now Bolt Factory should match whatever scaling you have set.
This is obviously not the correct way to fix this, but in lieu of something that actually works, this works for me and hopefully for you too. Until the plugin is updated again and it has to be done again at least.

For Windows, you have to first go to
C:\Users\(Username)\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\(Blender version)\extensions\blender_org\boltfactory and then do what Colonel Panic suggested
